# while loop replicating a for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hi im trying to do a disk scheduling algorithm (C-SCAN).I have a for loop with an if statement that works, however im trying to change it to a while loop or another option to remove the break statement.

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(initial<RQ[i])
        {
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }

while ( initial>RQ[i] ) 
{ 
    index =i;

    i++;     
}
```

The above for loop is what im trying to replicate as seen in my while loop. however it is not working the same way.
any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop of the form

```
for (initialization; condition; repetition) {
    // body code
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
initialization;
while (condition) {
    // body code
    repetition;
}
```

So your loop would be rewritten as:

```
i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    if (initial < RQ[i]) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Good point, I wasn't sure about that. I've removed that part

Comment: I believe OP's primary intent was to remove the `break` statement. However, your solution still has the `break` statement.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to solve easily without the other problem you noted. I find your solution with the `terminate` variable distasteful, since I consider `break` to be clearer.

Comment: I believe OP was hoping for a cleaner solution, which, as far as I can tell, does not exist. I fully agree with you that introducing an additional variable in order to get rid of a `break` statement does not make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility of removing the `break` statement would be to introduce an additional flag variable which gets set when the loop should be terminated.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

[...]

bool terminate = false;

for( i=0; i<n && !terminate ; i++ )
{
    if(initial<RQ[i])
    {
        index=i;
        terminate = true;
    }
}
```

However, I personally consider it better to use a `break` statement.